# Angular Reactive Forms - apply validation to every field without specifying it for every field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My scenario is simple: I want to apply a regex pattern validator to every field on my form, but I don't want to specify it for every field.

Here is my form:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.pattern(this.myRegex)],
      lastName: ['', Validators.pattern(this.myRegex)]
    });
```

I want the `Validators.pattern(this.myRegex)` validator to be applied to every field in the form, without actually having to specify it explicitly like above as it's too much duplication (bearing in mind I have many fields on my form in my code). I'd like my form to look like this instead:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          firstName: [''],
          lastName: ['']
        });
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-reactive-form-validation-example-jvgvy2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Look at FormGroup validators (not FormControl). There you can loop through all controls and validate.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way for this. The declarative way when you don't like, the other one is this:

```js
Object.keys(this.registerForm.controls).forEact(
  key => this.registerForm.controls[key].setValidators(Validators.pattern(this.myRegex))
);
```

But this will override all the other validators.

[Stackblitz exmaple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-reactive-form-validation-example-apq5hz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: yes, this would work but would override my existing validators. Is there a way I could simply add my regex validator to the form control?

Answer (score 0):

you can define an array of object

```
fields=[name:"firstname",validators:[Validators.required],name:"LastName"]
```

And create the form like

```
this.registerForm=new FromGroup({})
this.fields.forEach(x=>{
    this.registerForm.addControl(x.name,new FormControl(null,
        [...(x.validators || []),Validators.pattern(this.myRegex)]
})
```